# Find the anti-derivative of $\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the anti-derivative of $\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$.

I don't know where to start with this problem. I need detailed answer.

Comment: Do you know the derivative of hyperbolic trigonometric functions

Comment: Sorry I don't know.

Comment: Hint : use this  $\int \frac {f^|(x)}{f(x)} dx = ln(f(x))+C$ and u dont have to be sorry for anything! Find what f(x) should be

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Yes I agree with @user

Comment: Same thing as the other **two** homework question you posted: if you really needed a detailed answer, you would have at least tried to find it.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

$$\dfrac{d(e^x+e^{-x})}{dx}=?$$

---

Alternatively set $e^x=u\implies x=\ln u\implies dx=\dfrac{du}u$,

$$\int\dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx=\dfrac{u^2-1}{(u^2+1)u}du$$

Now use Partial Fraction Decomposition,

$$\dfrac{u^2-1}{(u^2+1)u}=\dfrac{Au+B}{u^2+1}+\dfrac Cu$$

or $$\dfrac{u^2-1}{(u^2+1)u}=\dfrac{2u^2-(u^2+1)}{(u^2+1)u}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:$$\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}$$ and $$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx=\ln{f(x)}$$

The given integral gives $$\int\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}dx=\ln \cosh x+C$$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me be **very** lazy and use the change of variable $e^{2x}=t$ that is to say $x=\frac 12\log(t)$, $dx=\frac 12 \frac {dt}t$. So, $$I=\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx=\frac 12 \int\frac {t-1}{t(t+1)}dt$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition $$\frac {t-1}{t(t+1)}=\frac{2}{t+1}-\frac{1}{t}$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.